# Find homology $S^n-f(X)$ where f is injective

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

> Let $f\colon X\to S^n$ be an injective function. Find the homology groups of $S^n-f(X)$ where:
>
> a. $X=S^k\sqcup S^r$
>
> b. $X=S^k\vee S^r$

The question above gives hint to look in both cases at $U=S^n-f(S^r),V=S^n-f(S^k)$. Nevertheless, the calculation became quite complicated in the first case.

On the second case, since $f$ is injective, $$S^n-f(X)=(S^n-f(S^r))\vee(S^n-f(S^k))$$

hence, $$H_i(S^n-f(X))=H_i(S^n-f(S^r))\oplus H_i((S^n-f(S^k))=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}& i=n-k-1,n-r-1\quad(k\neq r)\\ \mathbb{Z\oplus Z}& i=n-k-1=n-r-1 \\ 0& \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$Is that correct?

**EDIT:** Now I got stuck with the calculation in the second case. It appears that $U\cap V=S^n-f(X)$ and $U\cup V=S^n-f(S^{\min\{k,r\}})$ which turns the calculation to a very complicated one (I totally messed up with the indices). Am I right about the second part? should the intersection be something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't match any of the cases below?"

Comment: @DanRust see my edit please.

Comment: I would consider more carefully the union $U\cup V$. Remember that the images of the spheres $S^k$ and $S^r$ are disjoint in case a., and intersect in exactly one point in case b.

Comment: Thanks,but why in case a, $S^n-f(X)\neq U\cup V$?

Comment: nope, $S^n-f(X)$ is the intersection of $U$ and $V$ (remember that $(X-A)\cap(X-B)=X-(A\cup B)$.)

Comment: You also need to be careful when you say $S^n-f(X)=(S^n-f(S^r))\vee (S^n-f(S^k))$. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: I think that's correct since $f$ is injective. so $U\cap V=S^n-f(X)$ and the union is still a riddle. Still I have troubles finding from Meyer Vietorias the homology groups.

Comment: @WenchaoShang: draw a picture! You'll see that wedge does not behave like that under complementation!

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip so with the disjoint sum $U\cap V=S^n-f(X)$? what about the second case? How the union looks like, $S^n-f(S^r\cap S^k)$?!

Comment: @WenchaoShang, Dan Rust already explained that! $S^n\setminus(A\cup B)=(S^n\setminus A)\cap (S^n\setminus B).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to do the entire question for you because I think it's an instructive exercise which is worth putting in the effort in order to build your intuition for similar questions. What I'll do is a calculation for a special case. Let $n=3$, $k,r=1$. I'll do part b. (which is actually the easier case) our space is $Y_b=S^3 - (S^1\vee S^1)$.

b. To make things easier to follow, let $S^1_U$ be the image of the first circle under $f$, and let $S^1_V$ be the image of the second circle under $f$. We note that $U = S^3 - S^1_U$ and $V = S^3 - S^1_V$.

As $f$ is injective, $S^1_U\cap S^1_V = f(*)$ where $*$ is the point that $S^1$ is wedged with $S^1$, and $S^1_U \cup S^1_V = S^1_U\vee S^1_V$ and so $$U\cup V = (S^3 - S^1_U) \cup (S^3 - S^1_V) \\ = S^3 - (S^1_U\cap S^1_V) = S^3 - f(*) \cong \mathbb{R}^3$$
and
$$U\cap V = (S^3 - S^1_U) \cap (S^3 - S^1_V) \\ = S^3 - (S^1_U\vee S^1_V) = Y_a $$

We can put this into the (reduced) Mayer Vietoris sequence then, to get the exact sequence

$$\cdots \to \tilde{H}_4(\mathbb{R}^3)\to \tilde{H}_3(Y_a) \to \tilde{H}_3(U)\oplus \tilde{H}_3(V) \to \tilde{H}_3(\mathbb{R}^3) \to \cdots \to \tilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^3)$$

Recall that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contractible, so $\tilde{H}_n(\mathbb{R}^3)=0$ for all $n$, so the sequence splits into  short exact sequences of the form $$0\to \tilde{H}_n(Y_a) \to \tilde{H}_n(U)\oplus \tilde{H}_n(V) \to 0$$ hence $\tilde{H}_n(Y_a) \cong \tilde{H}_n(U)\oplus \tilde{H}_n(V)$. From here, you have to work out the homology of $S^3$ with a circle removed, which I'll leave to you.

Part a. is similar except the sequence won't split into nice short exact sequences in every degree any more (but will in most) because you'll have $U\cup V=S^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: but how I get in a the $\sqcup$ part?

Comment: in a very similar way as to how I got the $\vee$ part. Remember the wedge product of spaces is almost exactly the same as the disjoint union, except you then also glue the two spaces together at a single point in each.

Comment: After doing like that I get for b. the same result as I wrote in the question and for a. I get $$H_i(S^n-f(X))=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&i=n-k-1,n-r-1,n+1\\\mathbb{Z\oplus Z}&i=n-k-1=n-r-1\\ 0&else\end{cases}.$$ Is that correct?

Comment: Why not try writing up the full solution for others that are searching stackexchange for this problem? With all the details, others can then also check the validity of your solution.